# Get labeled image as ndarray instead of displaying it

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have an image loaded using [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html). I then label it using [scipy.ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label).

Now, most examples I've seen proceed to show the image using [matplotlib.pyplot.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). For example, [this one](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/#measuring-objects-properties-ndimage-measurements).

In order to do further processing, is there an easy way to get the same image that is about to be shown by `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` in the same format that e.g. `cv2.imread` would return (i.e. standard `numpy.ndarray`)?

Answer (score 1):

When doing

```
label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(mask)
plt.imshow(label_im)
```

`label_im` ***is*** a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: `label_im` is a `numpy.ndarray`, but doesn't have the same colors compared to the image that `plt.imshow(label_im)` displays - instead, the "colors" are labels (1, 2, ...). How can I get *those* nice colors as `numpy.ndarray`? :)